# Python - split, regex and condition

Tags: python, regex, string, if-statement, youtube-api

I have a target artist and would like to fetch its correspondent id, like so:

```
import re
target = 'Portishead'
videos = ['Portishead - Roads (Vg1jyL3cr60)', 'Portishead - Roads - (WQYsGWh_vpE)', 'Need For Speed (Linkin Park - Roads Untraveled) Music Video (7Lkq7bf6kU8)', 'Lawson - Roads (I-SOaSU0ieA)', 'Vargas &amp; Lagola - Roads (Audio) (Kd3s20GmPVE)']

for item in videos:
    artist = item.split('-')[0]
    # here I get whats inside parenthesis, not always an id
    video_id = re.findall('\(([^)]+)', item)
    # and here the id, which is always the last split item
    id_ = (video_id[-1])
    if artist == target:
       print id_
```

but my `if` condition is not working for the target artist. I print no results.

what is the best way of achieving this using a `for` loop or otherwise, considering that the real list is very large?

I want to fetch above "Vg1jyL3cr60"

---

**EDIT**: @Alexandre Cécile. I post here the entire function that calls youtube API, if you are interested in perfecting the function that narrows down the search for artist videos, once you pass track title and artist name. You will need a key for that, though.

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account


def youtube_id(track_name, target_artist):

    GET_CREDENTIALS = os.environ.get('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS')
    PASS_CREDENTIALS = 
    service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(GET_CREDENTIALS)
    YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
    YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"
    DEVELOPER_KEY = "mykey"

    youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION, credentials=PASS_CREDENTIALS,
    developerKey=None)
    # Call the search.list method to retrieve results matching the specified
    # query term.
    search_response = youtube.search().list(
    q=track_name,
    part="id,snippet",
    #maxResults=track_name.max_results
    ).execute()

    videos = []
    videos_ids = []
    channels = []
    playlists = []

    # Add each result to the appropriate list, and then display the lists of
    # matching videos, channels, and playlists.
    for search_result in search_response.get("items", []):
        if search_result["id"]["kind"] == "youtube#video":
            videos.append("%s (%s)" % (search_result["snippet"]["title"],
                                 search_result["id"]["videoId"]))
            videos_ids.append("%s" % (search_result["id"]["videoId"]))
        elif search_result["id"]["kind"] == "youtube#channel":
            channels.append("%s (%s)" % (search_result["snippet"]["title"],
                                   search_result["id"]["channelId"]))
        elif search_result["id"]["kind"] == "youtube#playlist":
            playlists.append("%s (%s)" % (search_result["snippet"]["title"],
                                    search_result["id"]["playlistId"]))

    print ("Videos:\n", "\n".join(videos), "\n")
    print ("Channels:\n", "\n".join(channels), "\n")
    print ("Playlists:\n", "\n".join(playlists), "\n")

    ids=[]
    for video in videos:
        artist = re.split(r'\s*-\s*', video)[0]
        id = re.search(r'.*\(([^)]+)', video)[1]
        if id and artist == target_artist:
            videos_ids.append(id)
            print ('VIDEOS IDS',  videos_ids)

    return videos_ids[-1]
```

Comment: I guess it should be `item.split(' -')`

Comment: `print id` -> `print(id)`

Comment: Where does your list come from? You mention performance and that it is quite large, so it will determine what the best solution is.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile python2?

Comment: pyhton3.7, sir.

Comment: @DerekEden Always a possibility, but unlikely IMO.

Comment: if you're not using brackets in the print statement and you are running to completion..then you are using python2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're having is mainly due to a space being present at the end of your match (since `-` splits on `-` and leaves the space behind it). Tcode below should work for you. It uses `re.split` to split on `\s*-\s*` (any number of spaces, followed by `-`, followed by any number of spaces).

I also cleaned up some of the other parts of your code. I added `.*` to the start of your second regex to capture only the last instance (and changed `[0]` to `[1]` to get the captured contents instead of the entire match).

The last portion checks to see if `id` exists and if `artist == target` before printing.

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##bZHBTgIxEIbP9inm5LbIkkUSMBoOHJQYV0UJSwygqbSwdaGtbcHw9GuXEvDgJJM006@df/7RO5cr2SpLsdbKODAcOWqW3EEXooGvCJtzyiK0FYwr66sTdPbnAmJ4VZRZwNmy@bVLW3PTTkhU/x@KAY9f3mx/nH9s9W3AnjhncKcMDHV1wqmQhZAwoKY4vhtJZ@iWrzgj8LixYg5ZJQdwJy2@O5@LdjG6Cr@l9McqeVJ1Hw@f6XCUCN4LQOanoxbO6VrfQEqXakVPdG/DhCKAH1jLXib99SDzItEMoYXXt3cAvLRgxTUCH7SasTLL8IbVK@Gwiaa2FvuM6oEkk2S2ZwU7cJyaee7BRm2K8eSdzC7ICW4e4EXFU8mOLboQNhMaV6GNkA4LRsryFw)

```
import re
target = 'Portishead'
videos = [
    'Portishead - Roads (Vg1jyL3cr60)',
    'Portishead - Roads - (WQYsGWh_vpE)',
    'Need For Speed (Linkin Park - Roads Untraveled) Music Video (7Lkq7bf6kU8)',
    'Lawson - Roads (I-SOaSU0ieA)',
    'Vargas &amp; Lagola - Roads (Audio) (Kd3s20GmPVE)'
]

for video in videos:
    artist = re.split(r'\s*-\s*', video)[0]
    id = re.search(r'.*\(([^)]+)', video)[1]
    if id and artist == target:
        print(id)
```

Results in:

```
Vg1jyL3cr60
WQYsGWh_vpE
```

---

Explanation of regex patterns:

- `\s*-\s*` this pattern matches `-` and any whitespace around them

  - `\s*` matches any whitespace character any number of times
  - `-` matches this character literally
  - `\s*` matches any whitespace character any number of times
- `.*\(([^)]+)` this pattern matches the last instance of the left parenthesis in a string

  - `.*` match any character any number of times (this is how we can ensure we match the last parenthesis as it's greedy and will match as many characters as possible)
  - `\(` match `(` literally
  - `([^)]+)` captures the following

    - `[^)]+` matches one or more of any character except `)`

Comment: Can you explain your artist regex? I’m not sure I understand it completely.

Comment: On the string "Need For Speed (Linkin Park - Roads Untraveled) Music Video (7Lkq7bf6kU8)", won't the code incorrectly produce "Need For Speed (Linkin Park" for the artist name?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile yes but your question doesn't cover that case (and what is the expected outcome for that string.

Comment: Which question?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile sorry, this question. According to the OP, the target is before the first `-`

Comment: Eh, he doesn't say so, it just seems that way because of his code. His code is really broken, and the string I shared is a perfect counter-example, so I hope he ends up explaining things a bit more. Until then we can't be certain, unfortunately. Tant pis!

Answer (score 1):

When you split the artist from the track, you are splitting on `'-'`. If you look at the actual strings, you'll see that there is whitespace around the hyphen, which will be included in the split result.

The solution is to `.strip()` the `artist` variable to get rid of the whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

you can change your code to the following, fixing the split issue and grabbing the ID (or whatever is between the parathesis):

```
import re
target = 'Portishead'
videos = ['Portishead - Roads (Vg1jyL3cr60)', 'Portishead - Roads - (WQYsGWh_vpE)', 'Need For Speed (Linkin Park - Roads Untraveled) Music Video (7Lkq7bf6kU8)', 'Lawson - Roads (I-SOaSU0ieA)', 'Vargas &amp; Lagola - Roads (Audio) (Kd3s20GmPVE)']

for item in videos:
    artist = item.split(' - ')[0]
    video_id = re.sub('\(|\)','',re.findall('\(.*?\)',item)[-1])
    if artist == target:
       print video_id
```

output:

```
Vg1jyL3cr60
WQYsGWh_vpE
```

if your desired output is just `Vg1jyL3cr60` as stated in the OP, you'd want to break the loop after the first ID is printed

looking at the data more closely, it is not always clear exactly when the artist name occurs (such as for Linkin Park and Lagola) so the current approach has flaws that aren't addressed in any of the answers

Comment: `re.search` will get the first item - the last item is sought after.

Comment: _"looking at the data more closely, it is not always clear exactly when the artist name occurs (such as for Linkin Park and Lagola) so the current approach has flaws that aren't addressed in any of the answers"_ That's a good point, surprised that no one else has mentioned it. We need some sort of clarification from OP.

Comment: think everyone (including myself) got caught up in making it work for the specific example :D

Answer (score 0):

Alright, here is a full working example with a new regex. It extracts the video's id, name/title, and that's it. I wanted to avoid making a bunch of assumptions about the format of the video's title, since it seems to follow no particular pattern or format.

---

```py
import re

vid_extract_re = re.compile(r"^(?P<video_name>.*)\((?P<video_id>\S+)\)$")

vid_str_list = ['Portishead - Roads (Vg1jyL3cr60)', 'i am a string which does not fit the pattern',
                'Portishead - Roads - (WQYsGWh_vpE)',
                'Need For Speed (Linkin Park - Roads Untraveled) Music Video (7Lkq7bf6kU8)',
                'Lawson - Roads (I-SOaSU0ieA)',
                'Vargas & Lagola - Roads (Audio) (Kd3s20GmPVE)', 'i am also a string which does not fit the pattern']

vid_info_lst = []

for curr_vid_str in vid_str_list:
    curr_match = vid_extract_re.fullmatch(curr_vid_str)
    if curr_match is not None:
        curr_vid_name, curr_vid_id = curr_match.groups()
        vid_info_lst.append((curr_vid_name.strip(), curr_vid_id))
    else:
        print(f'Regex failed on video str: {curr_vid_str}')

print(vid_info_lst)
```

---

Let me know if you have any further questions! :)

Comment: very nice. but mind that in te question I need a solution that passes a target artist and returns *only the video id*, for any video id concerning that target. in the example above, passing Portishead as an argument and returning one video id for this artist. I would accept and upvote if you encapsulate that in a function passing target and returning id if artist is found.

Comment: @data_garden How can we extract/identify the artist name consistently? As far as I’m aware, the titles follow no pattern that would make that possible.

Comment: @data_garden Should have clarified that my comment is based on the limited amount of information shared in your post. Depending on where the data comes from, the rest of your program and it’s purpose, etc., there might be a solution.

Comment: We pass the artist name. thats why it is target, and that' why I used as contidion. that suffices for this question

Comment: like `for item in vid_info_lst:
 if target_artist in item[0]:
  print (item[1])`

Comment: where `target_artist = 'Portishead'`

Comment: @data_garden Let me rephrase my question: How do we check, using only an artist name and the title of a video, whether the artist created/corresponds to that video. For example, who’s the artist in this title: “Need For Speed (Linkin Park - Roads Untravelled) Music Video (Kd3s20GmPVE)” That’s a trivial question for a human being, and an extremely tough one for a computer. The code you just shared uses a simple substring check, which unfortunately is incredibly ineffective.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202437/discussion-between-alexander-cecile-and-data-garden).

Answer (score -1):

### Method 1

Maybe, the following might be a bit closer:

```
import re
target = 'Portishead'
videos = ['Portishead - Roads (Vg1jyL3cr60)', 'Portishead - Roads - (WQYsGWh_vpE)', 'Need For Speed (Linkin Park - Roads Untraveled) Music Video (7Lkq7bf6kU8)',
          'Lawson - Roads (I-SOaSU0ieA)', 'Vargas &amp; Lagola - Roads (Audio) (Kd3s20GmPVE)']

for item in videos:
    artist = item.split('-')[0]
    # here I get whats inside parenthesis, not always an id
    video_id = re.findall(r'(?<=\()[^)]+(?=\))', item)
    # and here the id, which is always the last split item
    id_ = video_id
    if artist.strip() == target:
        print(video_id)
```

#### Output

```
['Vg1jyL3cr60']
['WQYsGWh_vpE']
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/LRSxpv/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/LRSxpv/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

### Method 2

Just in case, you might have had unknown number of spaces, then we'd take advantages of `re.split()`:

```
import re
target = 'Portishead'
videos = ['Portishead - Roads (Vg1jyL3cr60)', 'Portishead - Roads - (WQYsGWh_vpE)', 'Need For Speed (Linkin Park - Roads Untraveled) Music Video (7Lkq7bf6kU8)',
          'Lawson - Roads (I-SOaSU0ieA)', 'Vargas &amp; Lagola - Roads (Audio) (Kd3s20GmPVE)']

for item in videos:
    artist = re.split(r'\s*-\s*', item)[0]

    # here I get whats inside parenthesis, not always an id
    video_id = re.findall(r'(?<=\()[^)]+(?=\))', item)
    # and here the id, which is always the last split item
    if artist == target:
        print(video_id[0])
```

#### Output

```
Vg1jyL3cr60
WQYsGWh_vpE
```

Comment: You're outputting `video[0]`, it should be the last item according to OP

Comment: _and here the id, which is always the last item_ your code doesn’t grab the last item.